# loading image in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have this code

```
            cy.get('input[type="file"]').attachFile({
                fileContent: fileContent.toString(),
                fileName: 'test-image.jpeg',
                mimeType: 'image/jpeg'
            })
        })
```

The file is uploaded but when the file uploads its supposed to show the preview of the image  but it says that the file does not preview. It just shows something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuKAo.png

i have the same issue for pdf:
my code is:

```
cy.fixture('test-pdf.PDF', "binary").then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob).then((fileContent) => {
            cy.get('input[type="file"]').attachFile({
                fileContent: fileContent.toString(),
                fileName: 'test-pdf.PDF',
                mimeType: 'application/PDF'
            })
```

```
but the preview is like this:
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnKpN.png

The same loads well in normal browsers only failing when running tests in cypress
What changes do i have to make to make the image and pdf load/preview?
Thank you

Comment: In which browsers do your Cypress tests run? Have you tried using a different browser, e.g. cypress run --browser chrome ?

Comment: I tried in chrome only. I have not tested it in firefox. I will test and confirm for firefox

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this approach:

```
cy.get('input[type="file"]').attachFile({
   fileName: 'test-image.jpeg',
   encoding: "binary",
});
```

Comment: Hello
 i have added encoding: 'base64' for image and it loaded the image but for pdf i am still facing the same issue. I added encoding binary for it but i am still having the same issue. 
it happens both in chrome and mozilla

Comment:  congrats with `*.img`, regarding PDF try to use `encoding: "ascii",`

Comment: you can find all supported formats by clicking on this function `attachFile`

Comment: You mean i edit my current code for pdf and replace the binary with ascii? I did try it but i got the same result

Comment: please try to use different `*.pdf` file with an other size or so, double check if the file located inside `fixtures` folder, try different `encoding` format but I have working example with `binary`